# how to fix contains method with generics

Tags: java

My `contains` method works properly for smaller indices but then for big indices such as the test cases 1000, 2000, 2999 it does not work. I do not see why. I checked the output for the print statement in the loop which shows that the numbers I am checking for are present in the object array.

Assume the objects in array and element are int. data is `Object []`

```
public boolean contains(E element) {
         boolean flag = false;
         if (this.size() == 0) { return flag;}

         for (int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
              if (element == this.data[i]) { flag = true; }
              System.out.println(this.data[i]);
         }
         return flag;
}

@Test
public void mustGrowArray()  {
      OurSet<Integer> ints = new ArraySet<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        ints.add(i);
      }
      assertEquals(3000, ints.size());//passes
      assertTrue(ints.contains(1000));// fails
      assertTrue(ints.contains(2000));// fails
      assertTrue(ints.contains(2999));// fails
}
```

Comment: Compare with `equals`, not with `==`.

Comment: thank you! that worked but why was the error happening?

Comment: You can have two objects that are .equals but not equal. Eg. `Integer a = new Integer(1); Integer b = new Integer(1);` a==b is false, but a.equals(b) is true. I'm surprised 1000 isn't cached when it is autoboxed.

Comment: Another suggestion: instead of: flag=true you should return true; or break; just after 
-> it's faster as you don't need to check all the array

Answer (score 1):

`==` is not `.equals`!

Use `.equals` instead in this line,

```
if (element == this.data[i])
```

to

```
if (element.equals(this.data[i]))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Compare with `equals` instead of `==`

use this `for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    if (element.equals(this.data[i])) {
       flag = true;
    }
    System.out.println(this.data[i]);
}
```

To know the differences between `equals` and `==` operator go through this link:
[Difference between "equals" and "==" operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/)